# Z-index with fixed positioning not working in CodePen

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a page with a fixed vertical line on it, and some content that the user can scroll through. The content has a higher z-index than the fixed vertical line, but the line still appears in front of the content as shown in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/obliviga/pen/ExydrVN). I would expect the content to be over the line, not under it. How can I fixed this?

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}

.line {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 1px;
  background: tomato;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 50%;
}

section {
  padding: 100px 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<span class="line"></span>
<section>some text</section>
```

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? I don't understand what you mean by _"the line still appears in front of the content"_ and _"I would expect the content to be over the line, not under it"_. The whole 'in front', 'over', and 'under' isn't clear

Answer (score 1):

To place one item on top of another, both should be in the **same container**.

```
 <div class="container">
<span class="line"></span>
<section>some text some text some textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome text some textsome textsome text some text some text some text some textsome text some text some text</section>
</div>

    body {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 200vh;
}
.container {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
}

.line {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 1px;
  background: tomato;
  background: blue;
  
  width:15px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 50%;
}

section {
  padding: 100px 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<span class="line"></span>
<section>some text some text some textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome textsome text some textsome textsome text some text some text some text some textsome text some text some text</section>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
}

.line {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 1px;
  background: tomato;
  background: blue;
  
  width:15px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 50%;
}

section {
  padding: 100px 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
```